# Probability of numbers within a Latin Hypercube

Tags: normal-distribution, random

What is the probability of occurrence of numbers in a Latin Hypercube? If I have a 1 dimensional Latin Hypercube of 1000 numbers would the probability of each number just be 1/1000? Essentially, I am using the Latin Hypercube to sample numbers from a Normal Distribution and am then selecting a single number at random from the array of Latin Hypercube samples. How would I calculate the probability associated with a specific number after this whole process?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but in an $\overbrace{n \times n \times \cdots \times n}^m$ Latin hypercube, there are $n$ distinct symbols each occurring exactly $n^{m-1}$ times.  Thus, a random cell will contain any given symbol with probability $\tfrac{n^{m-1}}{n^m}=\tfrac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Thanks!So if I have a 1 dimensional Latin Hypercube of 1000 numbers would the probability of each number just be 1/1000?